# C code hits unexpected runtime error if I execute for loops sequentially instead of nested

Tags: c, windows, runtime-error

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/thMike/9e99d03fe99fa8d3bd58610dc9d6aa7a). Initial problem [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/permutations-of-strings/problem).

For some reason, this code runs perfectly:

```
for (int i = n - 2; i > -1 ; i--)
{
    if (strcmp(s[i], s[i + 1]) < 0)
    {
        k = i;
        for (int j = n - 1; j > k; j--)
        {
           if (strcmp(s[k], s[j]) < 0)
           {
              l = j;
              swap(s, k, l);
              reverse_sequence(s, k + 1, n - 1);
              return 1;
           }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

While replacing the inner for with a break and writing it after the first for like this:

```
for (int i = n - 2; i > -1 ; i--)
{
    if (strcmp(s[i], s[i + 1]) < 0)
    {
        k = i;
        break;
    }
}
for (int j = n - 1; j > k; j--)
{
    if (strcmp(s[k], s[j]) < 0)
    {
        l = j;
        swap(s, k, l);
        reverse_sequence(s, k + 1, n - 1);
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Hits a runtime error. Both print the permutations correctly.

What is even happening here?

Edit: If I add

```
if (i == 0 && k == -1)
        return 0;
```

after the if in the first loop, it behaves as intended. So it's clear that what happens is that it compares s[-1] (k is initialized to -1) with something and it crashes.

Comment: Their executions are not equivalent. In the second example, in the second `for` loop, `k` is always the last value of `i` you got in the first `for` loop.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question, not as external link

Comment: @joaomlneto the first for breaks on the first time you get a value for k

Comment: The second piece of code assumes that the first "hit" in the first loop is one of the elements you want to swap, the first piece doesn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo I might be stupid, but I have no clue what you mean

Comment: @Mike What happen if `strcmp(s[i], s[i + 1]) < 0` is alway false ? With the nested for loop, the second loop is not executed. With the consecutive for loop, the second for is executed ... with a value of "k" undetermined.

Comment: @Mike So k is initialized with -1. So when all your string is sorted, you have your bug as I have previously say.

Comment: @Tom's yep, you are right. If you can post that, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it was just some short code because I'm trying to get used to C. But I need to compare the whole string since it's not a substring of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that when `if (strcmp(s[i], s[i + 1]) < 0)` is always false, your nested loop behave correctly (the inner for loop is not executed), but your consecutive for loop will trigger a bug, because the following for will be executed with a value of "k" equal to -1 (since you say you initialize k with -1) and you will do an out-of-boud array access (str[-1]).

The if condition you added to fix your consecutive for loop is exactly what the first nested loop do implicitly : if not found, do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just replace nested `for` loops with consecutive `for` loops if the inner `for` loop is in some way dependent on the controlling expression of the outer `for` loop.

In this case, the controlling expression of the inner `for` loop is dependant on `k` which is equal to `i` and the controlling expression of the outer loop is dependant on `i`.

Try this out with simple for loops and you will understand.
The runtime error in the second case is probably caused because of some out-of-bounds memory access as the value of `k` is no longer regulated by the value of `i`.